# Serious discussion, should moderators get paid for their time?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I know this has been asked before, however things are a little different now.

Stack Overflow is a very successful commercial company. They have various streams of revenue and finding new streams every day. That revenue is based on the good-will generated by oodles of selfless volunteers. Which takes the hard and dedicated work by moderators to well... *Moderate* selfless volunteers.

Yes, there is the argument well they are volunteers and have always been volunteers. And my response is that is fine for a company that is *not for profit*. However, this company is a very ***for*** profit organisation.

The truth is, if there were no moderators this place would end up like a cesspool and *said* company would have no money. Good and dedicated moderation is vital to the company’s success... A fair day's wage for a fair day's work.

Is it a fair discussion that should be had? Should moderators be an elected and paid position?

Comment: There are more than just mods to moderate and maintain this site.

Comment: @Tom if you are saying people should be paid per interaction and rep, I'm picking up what you are putting down, and cant say I disagree. Though, moderators jobs are the last line of defense against Usenet 2.0

Comment: I'm not talking about reputation or interactions in general. I'm talking about moderation. Mods aren't the only ones who perform reviews, edit post and vote on their quality. So when we're talking about "fair", then why should mods be the only one being paid fairly?

Comment: @Tom Just because they are elected, and do one of the more vital roles of the site. And i honestly just think its a little predatory to have such a vital role not being paid when the company is making wheelbarrow loads of cash like 70 odd million a year. surely that can pay for mods

Comment: Related discussion on MSE: [Why aren't Stack Exchange moderators paid for their service?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247748/241919) (and its linked questions)

Comment: @AndrewT. I think this is StackOverflow specific, its the busiest site, and would generate the most revenue, what they do in DogsForCupCakesStackExchange.com is up to them :)

Comment: How can it be considered predatory when people volunteer to do it? Turn into into a paid job and they become beholdened to the company far more than the community

Comment: @charlietfl elected, sorts most of that out, i understand your point though

Comment: @TheGeneral except, Undo, one of the SO mods, answered that he didn't want to get paid. (and honestly, I'm kinda offended by your term for non-SO sites...)

Comment: @AndrewT. sorry for your discomfort, it wasn't my intention to offend. However, that's Undos personal choice I guess

Comment: @TheGeneral: I want to donate my unpaid labor to moderate DogsForCupCakesStackExchange.com. I suppose we’ll have to Area 51 first. I’ll be sure to put forward a proposal just as soon as I figure out what exactly it should cover—beyond the plight of moderators who aren’t even paid in cupcakes, of course.

Comment: i hope they get a t-shirt and Sweatshirt  and an cup that they can throw

Comment: A large part of the workload of a diamond moderator is clearing flag queues. That begs the question, how do those flags get there to begin with? Through the efforts of the rest of the population which does really hard work to keep this site from collapsing. Raiding review queues, flagging posts, answering questions on both the main site and meta, editing, quality voting... some people spend hours of their days doing that. And this serious discussion leaves them out in the cold.

Comment: @nbk Close. We get a t-shirt (with the SO logo), a bottle (also with the SO logo) and [a hat with a diamond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf?tab=reputation). The SO bottle is glass, so not a good idea to throw it...

Comment: @Machavity Tshirts are for some regions not enough, so i added the sweatshirt. The cup i  mentioned was because i sometimes drop mine when i read some quesions and as mods you have tp read sometimes even worse

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### No, absolutely not.

If we are paid, we become, for all intents and purposes, agents of the company (e.g., subcontractors). This makes us subject to their dictates and means we have to do what we are asked to do by the company, our employers.

In our current status, we are volunteers, which means we are free to follow our own conscience<sup>*</sup> and, ideally, that of the broader community which elected us and which we strive to represent.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> Save for some specific policies set by the site administrators that are non-obligatory for participation here for *all* users, like the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), and the [Moderator Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement), which must be agreed to by the volunteer moderators.</sub>

Comment: Imagine a world where you could be paid, and still be at arms length? Anyway, fair enough answer I guess. +1 Cant ague to someone who is doing the work that they should be paid :)

Comment: I don't think such a world exists? Getting paid implies reciprocal obligations.

Comment: There could theoretically be a "mod grant", just a blank, yearly personal grant to moderators for being moderators without any strings attached, while still having moderators be volunteers. I know the university I work at offers such grants to people in leadership positions at student associations, who usually make a substantial time investment without having any other source of revenue. There's enough selection within these association so people that are in it for the money would never reach such a position. Won't happen though since there's no incentive for Stack Exchange to do so.

Comment: Maybe people at https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com can design such world? Or prove it is impossible.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: asking that question will probably attract an answer like "Yes, it already exists in nature!" followed by a citation about some species of animal (non-human) that already does this, which is followed by another example of homo sapiens trying this and failing miserably (perhaps even being the cause of a large historically significant war).

Answer (score 10):

**Moderators don't want to be paid.**

What they want is to be treated by Stack Exchange Inc. in the spirit under which Stack Overflow was created, that is to say as valuable members of a community whose time and dedication towards said community is rewarded by seeing that community grow with the help of Stack Exchange Inc.

That is not what has happened. Instead, Stack Exchange Inc. has treated moderators like serfs, taken them for granted, refused to provide them with the tooling they need to do their jobs better, refused to listen to their feedback, the list goes on. Stack Exchange Inc. has abrogated the implicit agreement between itself and users that existed when Stack Overflow was originally created; in much the same way that the mega-rich abrogate their societal responsibility by dodging taxes.

As someone who has been here a long time and is heavily invested in this community, I understand why the moderators continue to allow themselves to be abused like this. But unless the mods are willing to take a stand against Stack Exchange Inc.'s vile exploitation, things aren't going to get better. We've all waited and hoped for years that the company will pull its finger out, and that hasn't happened, and no amount of hoping is going to make it happen.

Action speaks louder than words. Moderators, you have a choice - what will you do with it?

Comment: I was expecting something a little more well... explosive (from you) ;). Fair points though +1 however maybe some mods can chime in and validate

Comment: @TheGeneral At this point I really CBA to be explosive, because every time I do someone edits my post to make it more "nice" with the result that any punch I tried to impart effectively gets censored. One thing that this community needs far less of is the "be nice" namby-pambies. "Niceness" isn't words, it's intentions, and tough love is a thing.

Comment: Re *"no amount of hoping is going to make it happen"*: But another company or organisation, a competitor, might.

Comment: @PeterMortensen For anyone else to attempt to compete with SO's market recognition (brand) and SEO, which effectively makes it a monopoly in programming Q&A, would take a significant investment of time and effort.

Comment: This post goes downhill after the first sentence. Yes, we just had a terrible profile rollout (and we've had it out with SE devs on some UX issues since we heavily rely on userscripts), but there's another side there as well. In the relatively short time I've been a mod I've seen some of the terrible tooling [get improved by leaps and bounds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118). I have no idea what "vile exploitation" you think we're quietly accepting either (I'm not sure why you think Cody would accept any crap quietly).